# Dagger setup in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, installation, dagger

I'm having trouble setting up an Eclipse project for the Coffee example in the Dagger repo.

Below are screenshots of the error message and the Eclipse settings I'm using.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: On your 2nd screenshot, can you remove the four jars from your build path?  If that doesn't work, the only thing different from your environment and mine is my javawriter version is 2.2.1, I mention this because I saw a post where that actually mattered

Comment: Yup, that was it.  The javawriter version was the problem.  :)  Thanks!  If you repost your response as an answer, I'll check it as the accepted one, if you want the points.

Comment: I sure do :P, glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your version of Javawriter should be [2.2.1](http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/squareup/javawriter/2.2.1/javawriter-2.2.1.jar)