# Square Dagger IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class MyApplicationModule could not be loaded

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am using eclipse and Dagger 1.2.2 for my Android project. I managed to implement a test application with Dagger. But with my "real" application I get:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application app.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class app.MyApplicationModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application app.MyApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class app.MyApplicationModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4687)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class app.MyApplicationModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(FailoverLoader.java:45)
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader$1.create(FailoverLoader.java:40)
    at dagger.internal.Memoizer.get(Memoizer.java:56)
    at dagger.internal.FailoverLoader.getModuleAdapter(FailoverLoader.java:57)
    at dagger.internal.Modules.loadModules(Modules.java:43)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph(ObjectGraph.java:174)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000(ObjectGraph.java:138)
    at dagger.ObjectGraph.create(ObjectGraph.java:129)
    at app.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:17)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
    ... 10 more
```

This is **MyApplication.java**:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements InjectableApplication {
    private ObjectGraph objectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MyApplicationModule(this));
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void inject(Object o) {
        objectGraph.inject(o);
    }

    public ObjectGraph getObjectGraph() {
        return objectGraph;
    }
}
```

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="app.MyApplication" >
        <activity
            android:name="app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I also included the Dagger jars to the build path and factory path.

Comment: Do you add dagger-compiler dependency?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, I do. I checked everything again and again.

Comment: you also have referenced javawritter (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/squareup/javawriter/2.2.1/javawriter-2.2.1.jar) and javax.inject.jar libraries? What IDE do you use, Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: @Jospeh: Yes, also javawriter and javax.inject are referenced. I use Eclipse Luna. As already said, my Demo project works, but my "real" app won't start.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who might have had this issue as i did.  The issue i was facing is that i did not add a dependency in my gradle build file to allow dagger to do code generation ontop of my classes:

Add this:

```
apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

update: if you dont know where the apt plugin is, you can install it in your projects gradle file. My dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'
}
```

Comment: To add onto this, the full documentation for android-apt can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt

Comment: Why not add     "provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'"
instead?

Comment: "provided" did not work for me. when i changed it to apt, things work fine. i don't have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake:

You have to check "**Enable project specific settings**" for "Java Compiler" and for "Annotation Processing". Now my application throws a lot of other errors, but the Dagger code generation stuff works!

Comment: I don't even see such an option in Android Studio.

Comment: That's because  it's for Eclipse

Comment: aaaand boom goes the dynamite

Answer (score 1):

If you use multiDex, dont forget to activate it into YourApp.class

```
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

That solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        mavenCentral()
        ...
    }
...
}

...
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
...
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
...


  }

   configurations {
      provided
   }
```

Comment: With the android plugin, you do not need to create the `provided` configuration. Also, do not use both `provided` and `apt`.