# Module adapter for class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module

Tags: android, dagger

I was trying to use Dagger without Maven (using ADT Eclipse alone) and ran into this problem. I tried adding the jars in the annotation processing options, and using java writer 2.2.1 as I learned from [Dagger example built through eclipse fails with 'Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19555023/1400421) but it still didn't work.

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Solved my own question. The problem was not in the build config, it was when I was using plus(). I wasn't converting the modules into a proper array.