# Dagger used in Robolectric tests

Tags: android, robolectric, dagger

I want to use Dagger injections in my robolectric tests but I have trouble with set it up. Where is error in my code sample. How can I make this work?

#### My main module

```
@Module(
        includes = DatabaseModule.class,
        injects = {
                MainActivity.class,
        }
)
public class MainModule {
    private final MyApplication application;

    public MainModule(MyApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
```

#### My test module

```
@Module(
        overrides = true,
        includes = MainModule.class,
        injects = {
                TestMyApplication.class,
                MyApplication.class
        }
)
public class TestModule {

}
```

#### My production main class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Inject
    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
        inject(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

#### My robolectric test application class

```
public class TestMyApplication extends MyApplication {

    @Override
    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        List<Object> modules = super.getModules();
        return modules;
    }

    public void injectMocks(Object object) {
        ((TestMyApplication) Robolectric.application).inject(object);
    }
```

#### Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/info.korzeniowski.MyApplication.TestMyApplication. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
```

#### When I change in My robolectric application class method to this:

```
@Override
protected List<Object> getModules() {
    List<Object> modules = super.getModules();
    modules.add(new TestModule());
    return modules;
}
```

#### Result:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class info.korzeniowski.walletplus.test.TestModule could not be loaded. Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

### Update

#### gradle.build:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.2'
def daggerVersion = '1.2.+'
apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
compile "com.squareup:javawriter:2.2.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the `TestModule` and you are doing it right (`TestModule` must be in the list of modules returned from `getModules`). You can find solution for the second error here: [Dagger example built through eclipse fails with 'Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555023/dagger-example-built-through-eclipse-fails-with-please-ensure-that-code-generat)

Comment: Not working. I've updated my question and added gradle.build fragment. Is that correct? I use Android Studio.