# Annotation processing fails with Dagger 1.2.2, Gradle 2.4, Eclipse 4.5.0 Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, dagger

Dagger 1.2.2, Gradle 2.4, Eclipse 4.5.0 Mars on OSX 10.9.5.

Attempting to run a JUnit test fails within Eclipse: "Please ensure that code generation was run for this module."

This is a Gradle project in Eclipse with the versions shown above.

JUnit tests run successfully from the command line ("./gradlew clean test").

Project Properties:Java Compiler:Annotation Processing shows: all check boxes checked. Generated code goes to .apt_generated. No Processor Options are specified.

Project Properties:Java Compiler:Annotation Processing:Factory Path shows: dagger-compiler-1.2.2.jar is present and checked, javawriter-2.5.0 is present and checked, dagger-1.2.2.jar is present and checked.

org.eclipse.jst.ws.annotations.core is present but not checked (checking it and rebuilding doesn't seem to make any difference).

The "checked" jars are all being taken from my ~/.gradle/caches directory.

Nothing appears in the .apt_generated directory (I gather that generated class files are supposed to appear there; I've never seen any.)

Thoughts? [Edit: added missing word "line"]

Comment: I tried adding java.inject.jar to the Factory Path as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555023/dagger-example-built-through-eclipse-fails-with-please-ensure-that-code-generat?rq=1 but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem automatically from within gradle scripting and for all projects in a multiproject gradle project this is what you can do.

1. Define an eclipse.gradle file to include the following configuration based on gradle eclipse plugin

> ```
> //generate eclipse .project, .classpath, .factorypath files
> //References: https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder/wiki/Enabling-PojoBuilder-for-Eclipse-Using-Gradle
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
>
> ext { 
>     eclipseAptFolder = '.apt_generated'
>     eclipseSettingsDir = file('.settings')
> }
>
> configurations {
>     codeGeneration
> }    
>
> dependencies {
>     codeGeneration 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
>     compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
> }
> compileJava.classpath += configurations.codeGeneration
>
> eclipse {
>     jdt.file.withProperties { 
>         it['org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations'] = 'enabled'
>     }
> }
>
> tasks.eclipseJdt {
>     doFirst {
>         def aptPrefs = file("${eclipseSettingsDir}/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs")
>         aptPrefs.parentFile.mkdirs()
>
>         aptPrefs.text = """\
>     eclipse.preferences.version=1
>     org.eclipse.jdt.apt.aptEnabled=true
>     org.eclipse.jdt.apt.genSrcDir=${eclipseAptFolder}
>     org.eclipse.jdt.apt.reconcileEnabled=true
>     """.stripIndent()
>
>         file('.factorypath').withWriter {
>             new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(it).'factorypath' {
>                 project.configurations.codeGeneration.each { dep->
>                     factorypathentry(
>                         kind:'EXTJAR',
>                         id:dep.absolutePath,
>                         enabled:true,
>                         runInBatchMode:false
>                     )
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

2. apply eclipse.gradle file to all your projects. Here is how I do it in my root project:

> ```
> allprojects {
>     apply plugin: 'java'    
>     apply from: rootProject.projectDir.toString() + '/eclipse.gradle'    
> }
> ```

4. run the eclipseJdt task (gradele eclipseJdt) and generatae the .factorypath eclipse file that contains all the configuration you need for eclipse to use Dagger Compiler as Annotation Processor
5. Import or refresh the project in eclipse and get back to work :-)

Comment: Or you can use my `net.ltgt.apt` plugin which does all of this for you ;-) `gradle eclipseFactorypath eclipseApt` if you use buildship, `gradle eclipse` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Another developer here knew the answer to this question:

Open the Properties of the project that uses Dagger (use the project context menu, not the main menu).

Go to **Java Compiler: Annotation Processing**.

Deselect the **Enable Annotation Processing** checkbox.

Click **Apply**. You should be prompted to rebuild the entire project; yes.

Reselect the **Enable Annotation Processing** checkbox. Apply. Rebuild the project.

The generated classes should now appear in .apt_generated.

I don't know exactly how this might interact with the **Build Automatically** setting on the project, but I think it's safe to call this a bug in Eclipse. I will see about filing a bug against Eclipse.

Comment: In a gradle multi-project it seems one has to to do the Annotation Processing configuration for each project as opposed to just doing it at the top level. In a large project this is very tedious. Any one know how to do it once?

Comment: You must have m2e-apt installed for this to work transparently.  You may have to install it in Eclipse manually.